# Using jquery-datepicker in rails form_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It seems the jquery-datepicker gem- https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker doesn't work with a `form_tag`.  It works nicely with `form_for`, when it is set up like:

`<%= f.datepicker :first_day, :size => 6 %>`

but in a form_tag it would look like:

`<%= datepicker :first_day, :size => 6 %>`

When I use it like this it loses its functionality.  I have the gem installed, and all of the required jquery libraries, as it works fine with form_for.  Here is my function in application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.ui-datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Do I have to make some modification to this function?

Comment: The documentation you linked says: "Use it like this in your views: `<%= datepicker_input "user","birthday" %>`", can you try with `datepicker_input`?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with form_tag, datepicker_input still requires a model name, "user"...

I don't want to use a model, which is why I'm using form_tag.